# Calculating matrix determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

This is a very easy determinant to calculate, but I get two different results when I calculate it in two different ways.
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

When I used Laplace expansion right away I got:
\begin{equation}
\det(A) = 1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} - 0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} + 2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} = 1 \cdot (4 - 4) + 2 \cdot (4 - 3) = 2
\end{equation}

But when I rearrange the rows in the matrix and then try to calculate the determinant:
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \overset{r_1 \leftarrow 2 \cdot r_1 - r_3}{\longrightarrow}  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\det(A) = 0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} - 0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} + 2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} = 2 \cdot (4 - 2) = 4
\end{equation}

I have probably made a simple mistake, but I can't figure out where and I really want to get the basics down, before I move to harder examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation $r_1 \leftarrow 2r_1 - r_3$ does not preserve the determinant. Indeed, if you check the rules, the determinant is preserved if you *subtract a multiple of a row* from the *actual other row* (and not a multiple of it).

Suppose you did $r_1 \leftarrow r_1 - r_3$, then did Laplace expansion, things would work. Suppose you did $r_1 \leftarrow r_1 - 2r_3$ followed by Laplace expansion, then things would work. However, because you did changed $r_1$ to $2r_1$ during the row change, the determinant got multiplied by exactly $2$ , which came out to be the decisive factor in the end, since $\frac 42 = 2$.

Comment: OK, I understand, thank you.

Comment: I have one additional question. Does this rule, where you can't multiply the row you are doing operations on, apply to other similar sections (for example calculating row echelon form). Or can you do that ($r_1 \leftarrow 2r_1 -r_3$) in this case?

Comment: @urbanpečoler No, you cannot. The reason is the same : doing the operation $r_1 \leftarrow 2r_1 - r_3$ changes things about the matrix which are preserved in its row echelon form. The determinant is one of them. These operations are therefore not allowed there as well. The good news, of course, is that the other operations which are allowed in the determinant case ,are allowed for these ones as well.

Answer (score 1):

$r_1 \leftarrow 2r_1 -r_3$ is not allowed.

If you want to do row addition it is:

$r_1 \leftarrow r_1+\lambda r_2$ or $r_1 \leftarrow r_1+\lambda r_3$